# Will a server install suspend if I close the lid?

Tags: installation, server, laptop

I have a spare laptop HP Elitebook 8540p on which i wish to install Ubuntu SERVER 11 and keep the lid closed. I have installed Ubuntu server on a desktop before, but never on a laptop.

Will the server shutdown if i close the lid? Is there any BIOS settings that i can tweak (like disabling the graphics card) to optimize the performance? The server needs to run day in and day out.

Comment: It should keep on running if you close the lid. I think your biggest worries about using a laptop will be power usage and the reliability of the hard drives.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid

Comment: Not worried about reliability. The server is for running CI for a small team. Can i tweak settings in BIOS to reduce power usage?

Comment: Not a duplicate. That question is about Ubuntu Desktop..

Comment: It really doesn't matter if it runs normal ubuntu or server ubuntu, the question is about the operating system and what will it do if the laptop lid is closed.
And that particular feature is a responsabilty of the operating system configuration like in the link i gave before.

Also laptops aren't recommended to be used like servers, unless you can give them a really good refrigeration

Comment: @LnxSlck But all the answers there involve using graphical utilities. If someone could post one that shows how to configure this from the command line...

Comment: @EliahKagan Our great forum has so many answers, look at this one http://askubuntu.com/questions/93542/how-to-disable-shutdown-reboot-suspend-hibernate it's for command line configuration shutdown but it can be altered to suspend like so: http://superuser.com/questions/465450/is-there-a-command-line-way-to-disable-suspend-in-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered. If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Reduce Graphics card memory usage in bios (set it to the minimum) .

Ubuntu Server will not go to sleep with the lid closed, but its possible the bios might so make sure any bios related settings are set to performance and look for any power overrides.

> **This is important**, i recommend you do not close the lid, laptops are
>   not designed to run with the lid closed so it may get very hot and
>   cause damage. I have successfully used ancient laptops as *always on*
>   devices by removing the lcd panel.