# Ubuntu 14.10 asks permissions for everything

Tags: mount, permissions, sudo

I just made a clean install of Ubuntu 14.10, since I had a 14.04 that I had upgraded a few times. After the install, the OS asks root permissions for a lot of stuff I was able to do without issues before, such as

- rebooting or shutting down the system
- mounting the external hard drive
- sending failure reports when something breaks

Fortunately I ma a sudoer and it is just a matter of entering the password a few times, but it is starting to be annoying. How can I find out what's wrong?

Comment: Nothing is wrong. That is completely normal.

Comment: It is normal to have the password asked to shutdown? Without other users being logged in? It surely did not use to be the case in the previous versions

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste have you ever been asked the admin password when shutting down or rebooting?  Mounting that is normal but only if the disk is not owned by user. Reports I can agree on; ok. Andrea: please provide permissions (`ls -l` of the mountpoint of the disk).

Comment: Permissions are all 755, and the disk is mounted under `/media/andrea` (which is my username)

Comment: If you want to allow your user to run special command without being prompt for password, try this: [Specify password for sudo in script](http://askubuntu.com/questions/496204/specify-password-for-sudo-in-script/497238#497238)

Comment: (In any case I did not need special permissions for anything of the above previously)

Comment: @Letizia My point is not that I want to be able to do that with sudo - those should be actions allowed to all users

Comment: I don't know how this works in 14.10 but yes, you should be able to shut down without a root password.  Unfortunately I do not know the modern mechanism by which that works.  It was part of policykit/consolekit as described [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/93542/how-to-disable-shutdown-reboot-suspend-hibernate/93956) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/130520/what-is-the-most-ubuntu-way-of-preventing-certain-users-from-shutting-down-su).

Comment: @neon_overload After reading the links you mention, I think the issue may be that my user is not active, in the sense of policykit. Do you know a way to check for this and possibly make so that my user becomes active?

Comment: I don't know, sorry. I'm out of my depth at this point.