# Disable suspend / hibernate via the policykit

Tags: 12.04, suspend, hibernate, policykit

I am trying to run Lubuntu 12.04, but if the computer suspends I am unable to bootup again.

Instead I see the bios post, the hard disk light flickers once and I have to install again (I have tried to re-install grub2).

I am new to Linux and what I found that best answered my question [was posted by James Henstridge](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93542/how-to-disable-shutdown-reboot-suspend-hibernate/93956#93956).

The instructions say to create `disable-shutdown.pkla` in `etc/polkit-1/50-local.d/` but this directory does not exist, so do I create a folder titled `50-local.d` in `poolkit-1` or do I have to place this file elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `etc/polkit-1/50-local.d/`

You can find 50-local.d in this path:

```
/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/disable-shutdown.pkla
```

Comment: how can i check that it has worked other than by trying to suspend -i don't want to risk my system b/c i know of no other way to fix this problem than to re-install-

Answer (score 0):

If you get stuck in 'suspend' mode as you describe, like I did this morning, you don't need to reinstall the OS. Switch the computer off at the wall, and leave it for 15 seconds or something before you switch it on again. This got me out of the suspend death loop anyway.

Comment: the question was ` do I have to place this file elsewhere?` and @redonath no it goes in the same place! although you should post a comment here http://askubuntu.com/questions/93542/how-to-disable-shutdown-reboot-suspend-hibernate/93956#93956 to confirm that

Answer (score 0):

At terminal, run this following commands:

```
gksudo gedit  /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.upower.policy
```

There are two sections in this file, first for suspend and second for hibernate. Near the end of each section there is a line...

```
<allow_active>yes</allow_active>
```

Change "yes" to "no".

```
<allow_active>no</allow_active>
```