# Prevent shutdown when rsnapshot is running

Tags: kde, shutdown, rsnapshot

Since shutdowns during rsnapshot operation will lead to inconsistent/partial backups, I wonder how to delay the system shutdown while rsnapshot is active.

The task is complicated by the fact that I need a solution which is compatible with non-expert users i.e. I need to tell reliably to the user that he needs to wait until the process is finished and not to do a hard reset. Once this is the case shutdown should continue.

A possible solution could be to replace the action of the window managers (mostly KDE) shutdown/restart/hibernate buttons by a script which first checks if rsync is active and shows a message if this is the case. But I do not know if this is possible in KDE.

Answer (score 1):

Try making a script to enable and disable shutdown then move the executable elsewhere then in its place put a script that:

1. Disables shutdown
2. Runs the program
3. Enables shutdown

See [How to disable shutdown/reboot/suspend/hibernate?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93542/how-to-disable-shutdown-reboot-suspend-hibernate).

Comment: I understand that obviously /etc/polkit-1/50-local.d/disable-shutdown.pkla would disable the shutdown e.g. but which executables/scripts are called when I press the KDE shutdown button. I need to know this in order to replace it with my version.

Comment: But if you disable it then the KDE shutdown won't work either. Then just re-enable it afterwards as I have said above.

Comment: On my system creating /etc/polkit-1/50-local.d/disable-shutdown.pkla does actually not prevent shutdown. Probably because of this: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=294714 . This should exclude this method unfortunately.

Comment: I shall go and ask Google for some help.

Comment: Do you have a `/etc/shutdown.allow` ?

Comment: No, I don't have it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5928/discussion-between-acematrix-and-highsciguy)

Comment: I didn't find time for chat this week unfortunately. Did you have further hints?

Comment: I didn't choose continue in chat, it was automatic

Comment: Other that kill KDE whilst snapshotting, no.

Answer (score 0):

I recently solved a similar problem, see https://askubuntu.com/a/617395/368069

adapted to your questions the answer would be:

Create a file /etc/pm/sleep.d/00-check-rsnapshot. In this file check if a rsnapshot currently is active. If yes, just abort the script using `exit 1`. That's it. Suspend will be aborted.

Might work for shutdown, too.