# Prevent shutdown when tvheadend recording / KDE session is active

Tags: suspend, kde, shutdown, desktop-recording

I am searching for a way to prevent shutdown/standby when tvheadend (or vdr) is currently recording.

What I found so far:

- [Prevent shutdown when rsnapshot is running](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164139):
  Which I don't like because it requires tvheadend to have root privileges and the link referenced seems to provide variants which do not work any more.
- [TVHeadend Wakup](https://tvheadend.org/projects/tvheadend/wiki/Wakeup):
  Setting Wake up time works fine. But pm-suspend does not check if a KDE session is active but instantly suspends.
- [How can I make shutdown not require admin password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190):
  works only for a very special case: checks if users are logged in

I see two solutions:

- Either TVHeadend script calls some KDE functions to ask for KDE state (screen locked, user logged in etc) and issues shutdown/suspend calls as seen in the above example.
- or modify the shutdown behavior of KDE so it checks if any TVH recording is currently active.

I cannot find any docs about these two variants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a really easy solution!
Create a file `/etc/pm/sleep.d/70-check-recordings`.

In this file check if a recording currently is active. If yes, just return `exit 1`. That's it. Suspend will be aborted.

My script looks like this, it is based on [this at tvheadend](https://tvheadend.org/projects/tvheadend/wiki/Wakeup).

```
$ cat /etc/pm/sleep.d/00-check-recordings
#!/bin/bash
#
# this script sets ACPI Wakeup alarm and stops standby if a recording is active
# safe_margin - minutes to start up system before the earliest timer

# bootup system x sec. before timer
safe_margin=60

# modify if different location for tvheadend dvr/log path
cd ~hts/.hts/tvheadend/dvr/log

######################

start_date=0
stop_date=0

current_date=`date +%s`

for i in $( ls ); do
        tmp_start=`cat $i | grep '"start":' | cut -f 2 -d " " | cut -f 1 -d ","`
        tmp_stop=`cat $i | grep '"stop":' | cut -f 2 -d " " | cut -f 1 -d ","`
#       logger "$0: $i from $(date -d @$tmp_start) to $(date -d @$tmp_stop)"

        start_extra=`cat $i | grep '"start_extra":' | cut -f 2 -d " " | cut -f 1 -d ","`
        stop_extra=`cat $i | grep '"stop_extra":' | cut -f 2 -d " " | cut -f 1 -d ","`

        let tmp_start=$tmp_start-$start_extra*60
        let tmp_stop=$tmp_stop+$stop_extra*60
#       logger "$0: $i from $(date -d @$tmp_start) to $(date -d @$tmp_stop)"

        # if recording is active, immediately stop suspend 
        # tmp_stop > now and tmp_start < now 
        if [ $((tmp_stop)) -gt $((current_date)) -a $((tmp_start)) -lt $((current_date)) ]; then
                name=`grep -h -A 1 title $i | grep -v  title | sed 's/.*: "\(.*\)"$/\1/'`
                logger "$0: Currently RECORDING $name. No Suspend until $(date -d @$tmp_stop!)"
                exit 1;
        fi

        # only check future recordings
        # tmp_stop > now and tmp_start > now 
        if [ $((tmp_stop)) -gt $((current_date)) -a $((tmp_start)) -gt $((current_date)) ]; then

                # take lower value (tmp_start or start_date)
                # (start_date = 0) or  (tmp_start < start_date)
                if [ $((start_date)) -eq 0 -o $((tmp_start)) -lt $((start_date)) ]; then
                        start_date=$tmp_start
                        stop_date=$tmp_stop
                        name=`grep -h -A 1 title $i | grep -v  title | sed 's/.*: "\(.*\)"$/\1/'`
                fi
        fi
done

wake_date=$((start_date-safe_margin))

# set up wakeup alarm
if [ $((start_date)) -ne 0 ]; then
        logger "$0: Set Wakealarm for $name to $(date -d @$wake_date)"
        echo 0 > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm
        echo $wake_date > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm
fi
```

Now set up KDE to handle standby after time-out. If a recording is active, KDE standby is aborted by the above script.

See also [this in the MythTV documentation](https://www.mythtv.org/wiki/ACPI_Wakeup).

Answer (score 0):

Use [kaffeinety](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php/KaffeineTY?content=159860).  It is an application that prevents power management actions from triggering when certain applications are running.  You can then go into `system settings` -> `power management` and add the application to the list.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it soon, but not now. I fear that "add the application to the list" is not what I want, since tvheadend always runs. It only raises number of processes from 10 to 16 when recording.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script to shutdown and wakeup the system based on Tvheadend activity. It does not suspend your system while Tvheadend is active. You can find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/git-developer/autosuspend).

Comment: That's awesome, but we do like it if you can post the script here in case of link-rot, or at least give some more details...