# Ubuntu 16.04 immediately terminates all running programs on restart or shutdown?

Tags: unity, 16.04, shutdown, signal

When I choose restart or shutdown in Ubuntu 16.04, it immediately terminates all running applications. I'm not prompted to save open documents or anything like that - and I've lost work several times due to this (in particular, because various installs may prompt you to restart).

This didn't happen in earlier versions - on shutdown applications that wanted to would prompt me to save open documents, etc.

Is this change a by-design behavior (and can I change it), or is it a bug?

See also the discussion [on this earlier question](https://askubuntu.com/a/550921/523336).

Comment: I consider this a bug. Here's a report that may fit: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1281058

Comment: It doesn't fit to me. It's specifically dealing with the case where other users are logged in, and how to inform the user initiating the shutdown that his action may affect the _other_ users. It's not anything about gracefully terminating the current user's session and the associated applications. Can you confirm to me that on your system, with a single user logged in, it doesn't prompt to save open work e.g., in `gedit`?

Comment: I can confirm this. It doesn't wait because SIGTERM may be broken or isn't used any more. It just kills **everything** including other user sessions.