# I want to forbid guest to push reboot

Tags: reboot, guest-session

Every user or everyone it Guest Session can reboot computer. I want that Only root can reboot or power off computer. And about button of power off. Button must to be disabled. What I must do?

Comment: If you have physical access to computer, you can always reboot it by pressing reset button, or power button. This restriction makes no sense at all.

Comment: Likely duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/93542/how-to-disable-shutdown-reboot-suspend-hibernate

Comment: @javabrett I doubt it, this here is expressly about the *guest* account.

Comment: @Pilot6 I want nobody else root could reboot or power off computer. And button must be disabled.

Comment: You can't do it by software. There are hardware reboot and power buttons. You need to disconnect them. And also make power cord and fuses safe ;-)

Comment: @Pilot6 I can destroy button) and turn on computer with WOL.  Main problem about users. Only root will be use reboot and shutdown nobody else.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable to the GUI shutdown/reboot options, use [Polkit policies](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/pklocalauthority.8). Create a `.pkla` file in `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d` (say `00-disable-shutdown.pkla`) containing:

```
[Disable Shutdown, etc.]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.reboot;org.freedesktop.login1.reboot-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.power-off;org.freedesktop.login1.power-off-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.suspend;org.freedesktop.login1.suspend-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=no
```

You can add further sections which allow specific users or groups to use the buttons, or you can instead use `unix-user:guest-*` to specifically restrict guest users (whose names are usually `guest-` followed by a random string).

The button will still be present, but a shutdown/reboot option won't be:

[image]

See [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/1329094).