# Totally disabling shutdown?

Tags: power-management

I have a few systems running 14.04 LTS that my employees keep shutting down. I don't really have any need to shut the systems down ever, as long as I can reboot if it ever crashes. How can I totally disable the shutdown function?

Comment: Well they can always just hold down the power button. There's no way to disable that without a hardware mod, AFAIK.

Comment: And the shutdown command is still available.

Comment: I would recommend asking them not to or putting a notice up

Comment: You know the charlady shutdown? She simply pulls the server power cord to plug the vacuum cleaner in. That one always works (true story, happened probably hundreds of times around the world already)

Comment: Well, they could always unplug it or hold the button down :) And I don't think any of them are familiar with the `shutdown` command. I don't even need it to pop up a message or anything when they attempt to shut down...just for it to stay running.

Comment: This is actually a duplicate of "How to disable shutdown/reboot/suspend/hibernate?" with some very good answers
[HERE](http://askubuntu.com/questions/93542/how-to-disable-shutdown-reboot-suspend-hibernate)