# Ubuntu 17.10: prevent power off/restart for a user

Tags: permissions, shutdown, gnome-shell, guest-session

How can i prevent a user that i created for my kids to be able to power off or restart the computer?

I'm on Ubuntu 17.10 running Gnome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Asking them not to is arguably a much better solution.

Comment: Yes it would but it's not enough... :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable shutdown/reboot/suspend/hibernate?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93542/how-to-disable-shutdown-reboot-suspend-hibernate)