# GNOME3: Remove Power Off button for all users from the GUI

Tags: gnome, shutdown, gui, indicator

I couldn't find any solution to this. I need to remove the power off menu button (not the entire panel but just button highlighted in yellow hexagon) from the UI.

[image: top panel, far right corner of GNOME3]

How can it be done?

Comment: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2443/remove-poweroff-action-button/

Answer (score 0):

It's answered over here [How to disable shutdown/reboot/suspend/hibernate?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93542/how-to-disable-shutdown-reboot-suspend-hibernate)

Just creating a new file with the given config removes the button from UI as well without even a system restart.