# How do I ENABLE restart on lock screen

Tags: lock-screen, restart

Other people use this computer, with other operating systems.  How do I allow restarts when the computer is locked?

The exact opposite of this: [How to disable power off/restart option on lock screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/533111/how-to-disable-power-off-restart-option-on-lock-screen)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you choose "**Switch Account**" from the power menu at the lock screen...

[image: switch account]

then press the physical power button...

[image: shutdown options]

you should get the option to restart the computer by default.