# How do I configure Ubuntu 14.04 LTS such that at the login screen, a brief power button press initiates a clean shutdown?

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, lightdm

I have a system that runs an up-to-date Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, with Xfce as the window manager and the default login/session manager. (LightDM with the Unity greeter? It certainly looks very similar to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:LightDM_1.2.1_on_Ubuntu_12.04.png).)

What I want to do is to ensure that *whenever I press the power button briefly* (to trigger an ACPI shutdown signal), the system immediately begins a clean shutdown.

In a logged-in session, I simply went into Applications > Settings > Power Manager (the Xfce Power Manager) > *General* and set *When power button is pressed* to *Shutdown*. This works nicely.

In a console session, without having made any changes to that effect (that I remember), when I briefly press the power button the system initiates a clean shutdown. That's what I want.

**However,** if I do the same thing on the login screen, then **I am prompted for what I want to do.** I don't want any kind of confirmation. (Yes, I am aware of the drawbacks of that, and am willing to live with them. No need to educate me about that.)

For that final step towards my ultimate goal: **How do I configure the system such that also at the login screen, if I press the power button briefly then the system initiates a clean shutdown?**

GUI or terminal-based solutions are equally welcome as answers. (For GUI-based solutions, please keep in mind the fact that I'm not running the Unity desktop manager.)

[How to disable shutdown/reboot from lightdm in 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/453479/11751) seems to be basically the very opposite of what I want, and most of the other potentially useful questions I found are either dated or seem to only affect already logged-in sessions (which I have already solved). That said, if this really is a duplicate of some other question here, feel free to close as such.